# What's the difference between npm run watch and npm run hot in Laravel?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack

Because these commands are both available in Laravel, I don't quite understand what's the difference between them. But I do notice that `npm run hot` would not be effected if I changed scss files, which `npm run watch` will perform correctly.

Answer (score 7):

**Hot Module Replacement (or Hot Reloading) allows you to, not just refresh the page when a piece of JavaScript is changed, but it will also maintain the current state of the component in the browser.** 
[Check full documentation here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/hot-module-replacement.md)

Answer (score 1):

> It won't work right now for regular Sass files. The HMR feature is
>   specifically for Vue and .vue components.

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/92#issuecomment-273558018
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/233

If you are curious what the HMR actually means, you can refer to the official docs: https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/